# How to RequestMapping with ajax url instead of Spring form tag?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

urrently my adminMainPage is configured like this.
[image]

When you search with type value and keyword,

**I want to hide the memberList div without moving the page, 
and display the result list div.**

I have a lot of trouble here.
I have not put an action in the current form tag, 
and onsubmit = "return searchMember ();" I wrote this.

```
<form name="form" action="memberSearch.do" onsubmit="return searchMember();" method="GET">
    <div class="menu_btn_zone">
        <div class="member_management_btn">
            // left menu
        </div>
        <div class="admin_setPermissions_btn">
            // right menu
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="member_management_area" style="display:block">
        <div class="member_search">
         // member_search content
        </div>
        <div class="show_allMember" style="position: absolute;top: 155px;left: 1244px;font-size: 20px">
            //show_allMember content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="memberListZone">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align: center">회원 번호</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;width: 150px">회원 아이디</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;width: 100px;">회원 생일</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;width: 200px;">회원 전화번호</th>
                    <th style="width: 119px;text-align: center;">회원 이메일</th>
                </tr>
                <c:if test="${memberList eq null || empty memberList}">
                    <span class="noneMember">현재 등록된 회원이 없습니다.</span>
                </c:if>
                <c:forEach items="${memberList}" var="mList">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center;width: 100px;">${mList.idx}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">${mList.id}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">${mList.birth}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">${mList.phone_1} - ${mList.phone_2} - ${mList.phone_3}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">${mList.email_1} ${mList.email_2}</td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
        </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="resultSearch_memberList_area">
        // resultSearch_memberList_area
    </div>
    <div class="admin_setPermissions_area" style="display:none">
        // admin_setPermissions_area
    </div>
</form>
```

The code for searchMember () looks like this:

```
function searchMember()
    {
        var form = document.form;
        var type = form.type.value;
        var keyword = form.keyword.value;

        $('.memberListZone').css('display','noe');
        $('.resultSearch_memberList_area').css('display','block');

        $.ajax
        ({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'memberSearch.do',
            data: {"type":type,"keyword":keyword},
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(response)
            {
                alert('hihi');
                console.log('hihi',response);
            },
            error: function(xhr,ajaxOptions,thrwonError)
            {
                if(xhr.status == 404)
                {
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

and my controller code is

```
 // admin Main Page
@RequestMapping("adminPage.do")
    public String adminPage(Model model)
    {
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> allMember = aService.getMemberList();
        model.addAttribute("memberList",allMember);
        System.out.println("model is that ! : " + model);

        return "adminMainPage";
    }


// Url requested by searchMember()  
    @RequestMapping(value="memberSearch.do",produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView searchMemberList(
            @RequestParam(defaultValue="0") int type,
            @RequestParam(required=false) String keyword,
            HttpSession session)
    {

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        params.put("type", type);
        params.put("keyword", keyword);

        if(type == 1)
        {
            params.put("id", keyword);
            System.out.println("param is that : " + params );
        }
        else if(type == 2)
        {
            params.put("id", keyword);
            System.out.println("param is that : " + params );
        }
        else if(type == 3)
        {
            params.put("phone_3",keyword);
            System.out.println("param is that : " + params );
        }
        mav.addAllObjects(params);
        System.out.println("mav is : " + mav);
        return mav;
    }
```

This is my administrator page flow.

1. admin.do (Request to show administrator login page )
2. memberSearch.do (When searching for a member 
   (request of searchMenu() url when you hit enter in the input window))
3. adminPage.do (When you log in, the administrator main screen (the search box and the member list are displayed below))

However, when you search for a member, it looks for the adminMainPage.do request, not memberSearch.do, which has ajax url mapped.

Furthermore, I do not know why I'm going to visit adminPage.do because I do not have any requests in the current jsp file.

Did I make the mapping wrong? 
Can you tell me what I did wrong? 
And what do I have to do to get what I want?

help me please.

Comment: when you hit enter it is submitting the form. Write a javascript function to trigger the ajax call.

Comment: That function is searchMember().  @Rajesh